# Run shell command in PHP without using shell_exec

Tags: php, youtube-dl

My server currently disabled `shell_exec` for security reason so I cannot run the below command inside my php script. ( which I normally can when using ssh )

```
echo shell_exec('youtube-dl -f 134 http://youtu.be/8R_e09bOELs');
```

Are there any workarounds in PHP so I can still run the above command without calling `shell_exec` i suppose?

Any ideas are greatly appreciated. TIA

Comment: No, there isn't - for that specific PHP configuration. Your server might permit other means (cgi) or a different runtime, but only *you* can find out.

Comment: theyre recommending Suhosin but its unlikely to be compatible with the most recent php version so they believe it might cause issues with existing codes.

Comment: Are `exec` and `proc_open` disabled as well?

Answer (score 0):

If it's disabled - you can't. There are many other ways to download a video from YouTube. Just google: `php youtube download`.

Comment: yeah. but what I like about youtube -dl is its options. its sad that theres no other options to use it without enabling shell_exec. thanks anyway.